# Use TypeScript to extract narrowed object type

Tags: typescript

I have a type `MyType` that is equivalent to the following type definition:

```
type MyTypeEquivalent = { foo: 'one', value: number } | { foo: 'two', value: string }
```

How can I extract the type where `foo` is `'one'`, i.e.:

```
type DesiredExtractedType = { foo: 'one', value: number }
```

I am aware that I can do it programmatically, i.e.:

```
if (obj.foo === 'one') {
  obj.value // <-- type will be number
}
```

But I need the actual type definition, not the TS type inference.

Comment: `MyTypeEquivalent & { foo: 'one' }`?

Comment: So simple, thank you! Feel free to post the answer:)

Comment: `MyType & { foo: 'one' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MyType & {foo: 'one'}` to achieve this. You're telling TS that `foo` is `'one'`, it can infer the type of the rest of the object from that.